# How do I use a simple query to search a list of data from a table and return non-duplicate results in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

I am trying to loop through the data in a table, and using the data to search to return the results in another table.

How do I prevent duplicates from adding to the table? Note that the order of the query results adding are very important. So if the results are already added, I don't want them to be added again. Note that the original ranking done by the full search category is misleading, I don't want to use that.

I am using cursor, but I was told it can be solved using simple query; how do I do that?

Below is the code.

```
 ...

    DECLARE @subQ NVARCHAR(200)
    SET @subQ = ''

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT combination FROM @Subqueries

    OPEN cur1
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @subQ

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Results (app_id, rank, importance)
        SELECT app_id, rank, 1
        FROM CONTAINSTABLE(dbo.Applications, display_name, @subQ) KEY_TBL
        INNER JOIN Applications App
        ON KEY_TBL.[KEY] = App.app_id

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @subQ   
    END   

    CLOSE cur1
    DEALLOCATE cur1

    ...
```

Comment: It's stuck in a loop because of `WHILE 1 = 1`, which will always be true.

Comment: Thanks. How do I use a plain query? I wish to do that too. Tried before, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You used 1 = 1 in while loop. so it will be showing always true condition and resultant is that loop converted to infinite loop.

Change your condition in while loop.

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed a silly mistake. As I am not familiar with SQL programming. I have updated the question, do help if u can.

Answer (score 0):

try this while loop

```
DECLARE @subQ NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @mn int
DECLARE @mx int
DECLARE @val varchar(100)
SET @subQ = ''

;WITH CTE as(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) as rn,* from @Subqueries)
select @mn=MIN(rn),@mx=MAX(rn) from CTE

WHILE @mn>=@mx
BEGIN
select @val=somecolm from CTE where rn=@mn
--do here for each value of any column in CTE
SET @mn=@mn+1
END
```